# Wide to long in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data in the following format,

---

```
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

where `d` is

```
d = {'ID': {0: 1789, 1: 1872},
 'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'},
 'June_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 1, 1: 1},
 'July_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 1, 1: 1},
 'August_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'September_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'October_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'November_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'December_2018_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'January_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'February_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'March_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'April_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'May_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'June_2019_entity1_flag': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'June_2018_entity1_value': {0: 100.0, 1: 8000.0},
 'July_2018_entity1_value': {0: 100.0, 1: 8000.0},
 'August_2018_entity1_value': {0: 0.0, 1: 8000.0},
 'September_entity1_2018_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'October_2018_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'November_2018_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'December_2018_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'January_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'February_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'March_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'April_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'May_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'June_2019_entity1_value': {0: nan, 1: 8000.0},
 'July_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'August_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'September_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'October_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'November_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'December_2018_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'January_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'February_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'March_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'April_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'May_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'June_2019_entity2_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'July_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'August_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'September_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'October_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'November_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'December_2018_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'January_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'February_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'March_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'April_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'May_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 'June_2019_entity2_value': {0: 0, 1: 0}}
```

And I am looking to change it to the following format,

[image]

I have been trying melt, pd.wide_to_long etc. without much success. Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, post these dataframes as text rather than images. Preferably, post your input data frame's `to_dict()` output (i.e. `df.head().to_dict()`)

Comment: @rafaelc apologies for the previous one. I have changed it

Comment: Why are some of your entries defined as `September_entity1_2018_value`... Do you have bad data or is that a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `melt` + `pivot`, but a bit complicated so not strictly a duplicate.  You have some questionable values in your column names (just seems to be September_2018), which will be dropped by the regular expression.

---

```
u = df.melt(id_vars=['ID', 'Name'])

f = u.assign(
  **u['variable'].str.extract(r'(?P<month>[^_]+_\d+)_(?P<columns>[^_]+_[^_]+$)'))

f.pivot_table(
  index=['ID', 'Name', 'month'], columns='columns', values='value', fill_value=0)
```

```
columns                   entity1_flag  entity1_value  entity2_flag  entity2_value
ID   Name month
1789 A    April_2019                 0              0             0              0
          August_2018                0              0             0              0
          December_2018              0              0             0              0
          February_2019              0              0             0              0
          January_2019               0              0             0              0
          July_2018                  1            100             0              0
          June_2018                  1            100             0              0
          June_2019                  0              0             0              0
          March_2019                 0              0             0              0
          May_2019                   0              0             0              0
          November_2018              0              0             0              0
          October_2018               0              0             0              0
          September_2018             0              0             0              0
1872 B    April_2019                 1           8000             0              0
          August_2018                1           8000             0              0
          December_2018              1           8000             0              0
          February_2019              1           8000             0              0
          January_2019               1           8000             0              0
          July_2018                  1           8000             0              0
          June_2018                  1           8000             0              0
          June_2019                  1           8000             0              0
          March_2019                 1           8000             0              0
          May_2019                   1           8000             0              0
          November_2018              1           8000             0              0
          October_2018               1           8000             0              0
          September_2018             1              0             0              0
```

Comment: Smart with the `regex` ;)

Comment: It's probably overkill, but it was the only way I could get rid of that `September_entity1_2018` stuff :)

Comment: @user3483203 that was a typo. I am sorry abt that. but for some reason I am getting some errors in running this. still trying.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to `stack` and `pivot_table`

```
s = df.set_index(['ID', 'Name']).stack().reset_index()

x = s['level_2'].str.split('_')

s['col1'] = x.str[0] + x.str[1]
s['col2'] = x.str[2] + x.str[3]

s.drop('level_2', 1).pivot_table(columns='col2', values=0, index=['Name', 'col1'])
```